# Play Games Services and LibGDX: How to sign-in correctly?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-play, google-play-games

According to the 
[Quality Checklist for Google Play Games Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/checklist) a game should show the sign-in dialog when it's started for the first time, but when the dialog is canceled, then the sign-in dialog shouldn't pop up anymore. 
I'm trying to achieve this in LibGDX with [BaseGameUtils](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils).

So far, I got my Android class in which the [GameHelper](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper.java) is initialized. Then I call `gameHelper.setConnectOnStart(false)` because I want to start the sign process from my game code. For that purpose, I got an Interface.

For my problem to solve, I was thinking of a boolean inside my mainGame which indicates whether the sign-in dialog was shown before or not. When the game is started, I will look in my sharedPreferences and if theres an entry which says that the dialog was shown before then the boolean will be true. When the game is closed the boolean will be saved to the sharedPreferences.

How do I know when to set the boolean inside the mainGame to true, so that the next time the game is started no dialog will be shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by setting `gameHelper.setMaxAutoSignInAttempts` to 1.

```
 gameHelper.setConnectOnStart(false);
 gameHelper.setMaxAutoSignInAttempts(1);
```

If the sign-in dialog is canceled, it won't be shown anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember exactly because its been a long time but you can set a listener in onActivityResult() of AndroidLauncher. Something like:

```
if(requestCode == GameHelper.RC_RESOLVE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
{
    //user cancelled sign in process
}
```